# How to call a helper function of an object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

I have an object where I have helper functions that will schedule notifications based on what time. I am calling the function in a redux action after the user presses a button to schedule the notification.

I am receiving the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating _'ScheduleNotification.default.startReminder')"

I tried calling it on the button press as well as in the action and I receive the same error both times.

My schedule notifications object-

```
export const scheduleNotification = {
  startReminder: {
    async function(item) {
      const permission = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
      if (permission) {
        Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(
          {
            title: 'Reminder:',
            body: `${item.text} now`
          },
          {
            time: item.date
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.log('cannot send notification without permission.');
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Then my action where I am calling the function-

```
export const startReminder = (item) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: START_REMINDER,
      id: item.id
    });
    scheduleNotification.startReminder(item);
  };
};
```

Instead of the notification being scheduled the second I press the button the error message appears. I can provide more code if needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made `scheduleNotification.startReminder` an object with one property - an unnamed function. You've got too many curly braces in your code. What you want is probably this:

```
export const scheduleNotification = {
  async startReminder(item) {
    const permission = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    if (permission) {
      Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync({
        title: 'Reminder:',
        body: `${item.text} now`
      }, {
        time: item.date
      });
    } else {
      console.log('cannot send notification without permission.');
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that however that did not solve the problem. I am still getting the undefined is not an object error. Do I have to change the way I call the function at all?

Comment: @goolius_boozler how do you import `scheduleNotification`?

Comment: Ah that's what it was. I put the curly braces around it and it worked perfectly. Thank you.